# Wordpress theme options keep disappearing

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I guess this is more of a `has this happened to you and have you fixed it?` type of question. I have made a customer wordpress theme, and all was fine until today. My theme options disappeared. They were stored in a serialized array in the DB, and the row and serialized array are still there, but none of the saved values are called anymore.

Have you run into this?

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you using?  Does your theme have a name and version also?

Comment: 3.4.1 and its FruitBowlv1, version 1. Its not released to public.